# Spring boot graphql No graphql schema files found on classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

I developed a backend application using mongodb, spring-boot and graphql. I am using Jetbrains IDEA IDE. Project can be run on my development machine but it can't run on another computer.
Graphql gives errors.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/autoconfigure/tools/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No graphql schema files found on classpath with location pattern '"**/*.graphql"'.  Please add a graphql schema to the classpath or add a SchemaParser bean to your application context
```

First, I packaged my project for jar file. I tried to run it and got the same error.
Therefore, I cloned my project and built it from source code and I tried to run directly from source code. But again same error throwed.

My application.yml

```
graphql:
  tools:
    schema-location-pattern: "**/*.graphql"
  playground:
    enabled: true
  servlet:
    max-query-depth: 5
    exception-handlers-enabled: true
```

My pom.xml dependencies and build part

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>voyager-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.85</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-translate</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.mongodb.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I do not know nothing about GraphQL, but could it be that the error text 'No graphql schema files found on classpath' gives a hint to the solution?

Comment: Yeah, i searched it  but i dont find any solution. I edited my question title correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says you don't have any schemas defined or they are wrong!

```
No graphql schema files found on classpath with location pattern '"**/*.graphql"'.  Please add a graphql schema to the classpath or add a SchemaParser bean to your application context
```

Comment: I have schema files under resource folder, i checked many times it and project run correctly in my computer.

Comment: Do you have an idea, why they cannot be found?

Comment: I think I solved this problem that by remove schema-location-pattern from application.yml and I change extensions from *.graphlq to *.graphqls. Now project works.

Comment: That’s the normal file ending in java graphql schemas. But you can still implement a custom schemaparser, so you can use the standard graphql file endings.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the Kickstarter dependencies with the following

```
compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-spring-boot-starter', version: 
'5.0.2'
compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-java-tools', version: '5.2.4'
compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphiql-spring-boot-starter', version: 
'3.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part  `No graphql schema files found on classpath with location pattern '"**/*.graphql"'` you can see the `"`, what breaks the path. It should solve. Remember that the path is relative to `resources` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem that by remove schema-location-pattern from application.yml and I change extensions from *.graphlq to *.graphqls. Now project works.